# C# Call EXE from console app

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console app that does a number of things.  One of the steps involves calling an EXE (AzCopy).  I've successfully run this type command in a prompt and it looks like this:

```
AzCopy /Source:https://mysite.table.core.windows.net/MYTABLE/ /SourceKey:SOURCEKEY /Dest:C:\export /Manifest:MYTABLE
```

I need to run this script in the middle of a console app's execution.  I've seen a number of different ways to do this, but none seem to work.  I've tried this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", command);
```

And this:

```
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("AzCopy", command);
```

And this:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

None seem to actually kick off the AzCopy call.  What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", command);` should work.

But you need to add `/C` at the beginning of your command.

Something like this:

```
"/C AzCopy /Source:https://mysite.t........................................."
```

Comment: @im1dermike: What do you mean by "did nothing". Can you see the command prompt starting? Does it show any error?

Comment: I forget if it was when I included "/C" or when I omitted it, but one of them showed a separate command window opening.  In either case, the command was not executed, no output occurred in either window, etc.

Comment: When you open the cmd manually and enter your command, does it work?

Comment: @im1dermike: Add "/K AzCopy / ..." and see if you get any error on console. "/K .. " supposed keep the cmd open. So you can see the error if any.

Comment: Now I'm seeing that it's complaining that AzCopy is not recognized.  I added the AzCopy path to my environment PATH and it's recognized in a cmd prompt when I open it directly.  It would seem calling cmd through Process.Start() is unable to resolve the environment PATH. I'll try specifying the whole path.

Comment: That was it.  Is there any way to make the app to execute the cmd calls synchronously, waiting for each cmd to complete before proceeding?

Comment: Also that only seems to execute the first call.  I'm looping through and calling the command a number of times.